# create dynamic dynamic data wih canvas js with shfting data

Tags: javascript, json, dynamic, graph, canvasjs

I want to display dynamic data with `canvasjs` like [here](https://canvasjs.com/html5-javascript-dynamic-chart/) but i have some problem with shifting my data. My data just grow up but it's not shifted, this my js code

```
        var updateInterval = 1000;
        var dataLength = 10;
        function updateChart(){
            function addData (data){

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    dataPoints1.push({
                        x: new Date(data[i].datta0),
                        y: data[i].datta1
                    });
                    dataPoints2.push({
                        x: new Date(data[i].datta0),
                        y: data[i].datta2
                    });
                }

            }
            $.getJSON("http://localhost/graphTest/graph1/data.php", addData); 

            //data will be shifting
            if ((dataPoints1.length && dataPoints2.length) > dataLength) {
                dataPoints1.shift();
                dataPoints2.shift();
            }

            chart.render();         

        };


        updateChart(dataLength);    
        setInterval(function(){updateChart()}, updateInterval);

        chart.render();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you upload your data??

Comment: this my link code [link](https://github.com/mahmadakbar/DynamicCanvasJS)